# Acer Monitor - No Response to Power Supply?

Tags: display, power-supply, hardware-failure

Model No is S231HL, for reference.

As I was packing to leave my dorm, I unplugged it for the first time in a long time. It was working just a few minutes before this. I then realized I wasn't sure which cord was which between it and my external harddrive, so I plugged both back in. I believe that I got the cords correct on the intial guess (but could be wrong), thus one possible symptom of the problem is that the incorrect power cord was plugged in at some point.

In any case, the correct power cord now exhibits absolutely no response from the monitor. The monitor's power button does not light or exhibit response when pressed, and the screen is, of course, black. I can't really provide any more information; simply nothing happens when the monitor is plugged in.

The power supply is split into two parts, and the part that connects to an actual outlet is firmly plugged into the miniature power-box. The power-box lights up upon connection to an outlet.

Any idea what could be going on here?

```
Incorrect Power Supply: 12V, 2A
Correct Power Supply: 19V, 2.1A
```

Since the incorrect power supply inputs less voltage than the correct one, it doesn't seem like the incorrect one could have fried it...

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the confusion between the cords... if the adapter fit, it probably wasn't the wrong voltage. Is it possible that the monitor was damaged in your move? I hate to ask the question but... have you tried other outlets?

Comment: I have tried other outlets (both my dorm and my house). I tested it before the move, actually. I literally removed the cord, possibly plugged in a wrong cord, and then a plugged in a different cord (so depending on the order I plugged in the two cords, I may or may not have inserted the extra one0. The monitor did not move throughout the whole process, until I ran out of time and had to leave my dorm. The incorrect cord doesn't completely fit, but it still inserts into the hole slightly, but it has less voltage and current so it doesn't seem dangerous.

Comment: Use a voltmeter to check if the power supply is actually working. And a few years back I remember frying an Ethernet switch by plugging in a lower voltage power supply (5V instead of 7,5V), so that may be the case here. Also check if the PSUs have the same polarity.

Comment: @André Assuming polarity means AC vs DC (Sorry, I'm a CS guy, I don't get hardware), then both of them expect a DC current. Unfortunately, I don't have convenient access to a voltmeter, so it is difficult to run that test.

Comment: @mathepic polarity is **+** and **-**, your adapters may have [symbols like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zsp7C.png) that tell their polarity.

Comment: @André Thanks. They both have the negative polarity.

Comment: @André I mean in the picture you showed, the order of the negative parity. Edit: Actually, they are both "positive" (- then +). They don't seem to be inverted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14389/discussion-between-andre-and-mathepic)

Comment: Same monitor, same problem. The power supply is fine (verified by multimeter), but I get nothing. One day it was fine, the next: Dead.

Answer (score 1):

Low voltage can be harmful but usually just with items that have motors.  In most modern electronics if the supply voltage drops, the devices draw more current in order to keep running which can result in overheating.

Anyway, it's a pretty simple to troubleshoot in the end. Getting the tools you need is a different story... Here are your options for troubleshooting.

1. Find another power supply with the same Volts and Amps (or very very close) and try that.  If you still get nothing from your monitor and you have tried multiple outlets, then the monitor has gone bad. You could order a new power supply off amazon if you needed to.
2. Find someone with a multimeter.  You are in a dorm so I assume you go to college.  Find an engineering student with one and test the power supply you have.  You can also pick one up from a hardware store for very cheap.  I did a quick search on google (cheers for the part number) and I believe that [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002W07VLW) is the supply that goes with your monitor. When it's time to measure the voltage, put one of the leads inside the silver connector (the piece that plugs into the monitor) and touch one to the outside of the silver barrel part.  If you see 19V coming through then the power supply is fine.  If you get numbers jumping up and down or just 0, then the supply is most likely damaged. If the hole in the barrel of the connector is too small for the lead to fit into, try wrapping a piece of wire around the lead and thread that inside.  You have to make sure you have a solid connection or the numbers will jump around and look as if it's bad, even if it's not.

A multimeter (voltmeter) is a great tool to have.  I think it would be worth purchasing, probably only 10 bucks or so. If you end up getting one, measure the wall sockets just for good measure.

In the end, if it's too much of a hassle to troubleshoot with the meter, you can just order a new supply.  It's a 200 dollar monitor and spending 20 bucks, while annoying, seems worth it to me.